# Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-start" library

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, themes

When I run my project on Tomcat server, it shows this error:

> Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-start" library

Here's the stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-start" library
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


root cause 

javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-start" library
    org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeTheme(HeadRenderer.java:130)
    org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:92)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:824)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1641)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is there 'theme.css' file on the server?

Comment: no there is not any theme.css file on the server,

Answer (score 4):

This just means that the `primefaces-start` theme isn't being installed in the webapp.

As per the [PrimeFaces themes homepage](http://primefaces.org/themes), you need to install it via either an additional Maven `pom.xml` entry, or if you're not using Maven, by manually downloading the theme JAR file from [PrimeFaces repository in Maven](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/).

[The PrimeFaces start theme is available here](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/start/), the currently latest version is [1.0.10](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/start/1.0.10/). So just grab the JAR over there, the [start-1.0.10.jar](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/start/1.0.10/start-1.0.10.jar) and drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder the usual way.

Comment: Thanks DMity and BalusC, my problem is resolved, actually start theme is not being installed, i just download it now its runing........Thanks again for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Install the last version resolved problem for me. primefaces 6.1

- if you use maven, include in the pom.xml:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>6.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- if not use maven download primefaces 6.1 library and paste in the folder *WebContent/WEB-INF/lib*

Comment: Your answer is about installing PrimeFaces itself, not a specific theme. If PrimeFaces itself is not installed. You can never get the error in the question